# How to move hint down

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to customize the [TextInputLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ6e6.png) so that the hint is located below the border.
It is necessary that the borders are inseparable, and the hint is slightly higher than the body text. Can I somehow implement this?

Comment: The hint is drawn by helper class CollapsingTextHelper which is available in private-package scope. You can access the field via reflection but accessing private field is only available on pre Orea devices

Comment: You can also look into this https://medium.com/omisoft/textinputlayout-styling-8b36a5e0d73c

Answer (score 0):

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   android:id="@+id/default_text_input_layout"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="10dp"
   android:hint="Default"
   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       android:id="@+id/default_edit_text"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```